# Missing Extensiblity Item template on a VSIX project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, vsix, vs-extensibility, visual-studio-sdk

I have just installed VS 2013 SDK to my computer which runs Windows 7 beside VisualStudio 2013 ultimate.
So I have all Extensibility project templates listed on "**Add Project**" dialogue box. But there is no Extensibility node hence corresponding Item Template on "**Add Item**" dialogue box.
I have reinstalled SDK as well as installing Update 5 on Visual Studio but it didn't work.
By the way my project's target framework is 4.5
Do you have any idea what the catch is ?

Comment: From Add/Remove Programs in the Control Panel, try repairing VS2013 - you might even be able to choose to install the Extensibility features from there.

Comment: @AndersKellerCarstensen, I did that. Nothing changed :(

Comment: I don't see the extensibility node in "Add Item" dialog too. Why do you think it should be there in VS 2013?

Answer (score 0):

Visual studio appears to use the `<ProjectTypeGuids>` list in the *proj file to determine what to show in the add item dialog.

I had the same problem in VS 2017 with a project that was updated from 2013 to 2015 and now to 2017. In the first property group element, see if your project type guids matches this...

`<ProjectTypeGuids>{82b43b9b-a64c-4715-b499-d71e9ca2bd60};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}</ProjectTypeGuids>`

... my project was totally absent this element. You may or may not also need to add `<MinimumVisualStudioVersion>15.0</MinimumVisualStudioVersion>` and possibly others. If the problem continues, try creating a new VSIX project and comparing the two proj files for any other substantive differences.